# How to wget a website and then export all the pages into a single pdf?

Tags: pdf

IS there any way i can do that?

Answer (score 2):

I did this once. It was almost 10 years ago, however, so I don't remember the details.

I used:

- `wget` to download the pages
- `html2ps` to convert the individual pages to PostScript
- `ps2ps` to splice the individual PostScript files together
- `ps2ps` again, to put 4 pages on 1

Then I sent the PostScript file to the printer. Since you want PDF you could add an additional step of `ps2pdf`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could write an AppleScript to automate Safari to do the printing (and the fetching, if you'd like, though you can drive wget from AppleScript using `do shell script`). If you don't fancy using AppleScript, you could use Automator instead; the result would be pretty much the same.

BTW if you aren't using Mac OS X, it wasn't clear from the question you asked :-)

Comment: But why would you /assume/ Mac OS X?

Comment: I didn't assume Mac OS X. I provided one way for Nick Long to export all the pages in a website into a single PDF. He asked for _any_ way.

Comment: This is true he did state is there ANY WAY to do it. Rich B provided a way.

Comment: Sorry I meant Graham Lee... Is there a way to edit a comment?

Comment: no, but you can delete them and re-comment should you desire. Not sure whether that needs a particular reputation or not.

Comment: "This is true he did state is there ANY WAY to do it." No, he specifically mentioned wget, which Graham's answer ignored.